# Is Github.com source code open source?

Tags: github, open-source

... or the shoemaker's children go barefoot?

I would like to fix some styling & have an idea for the feature (and a lot of free time) but I cannot find any github.com page on github.com.

Comment: No, GitHub is not open source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about business decisions and contributing to a third party.

Answer (score 38):

GitHub isn't open-source, but you can apply your ideas on an (open-source) GitHub-look-alike:

### [GitLab](https://www.gitlab.com/)

A ruby application [with its source code here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq)).
They accept [suggestions](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general) and [pull requests](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pulls)

[image: https://www.gitlab.com/images/screens/gitlab_dash.png]

### [gogs.io](http://gogs.io/) (less active than gitea)

Update 2015: you also have other GitHub-look-alike in [Go](http://golang.org):

[image: http://gogs.io/imgs/screenshoots/5.png]

### [gitea.com](https://gitea.com/)

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/a5d123bbc466ef6b18a7b7ffce4553d97598e9b3e8ee8d12b44ef5e40964d74c/68747470733a2f2f646c2e67697465612e696f2f73637265656e73686f74732f6272616e636865732e706e67]

### [GitBLit](http://gitblit.com/)

[image: http://gitblit.com/screenshots/00c.png]

Comment: "GitHub isn't open-source, because they have a commercial offer based on it" seems to imply that you can't charge for open source software, but actually they could open source it and continue to have a commercial offering, if they wanted.

Comment: What about Gitea, which is based on gogs?

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 Good point. I am using gitea myself at work at the moment. It wasn't created in 2014, when I originally wrote that answer. I have edited it to include gitea.

Answer (score 12):

I was wondering the same thing!

They seem to have some open source code but not the entire code base.

check it out here: https://github.com/github